# Is BuildConfig.DEBUG still bugged?

Tags: android

According to [this Blog](http://www.digipom.com/be-careful-with-buildconfig-debug/) BuildConfig.DEBUG was unreliable.
Since my colleague is using BuildConfig.DEBUG extensively (seemingly like test code in production code), I'm wondering if this flag is still as bugged as it was a few years ago.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio and Gradle for Android, `BuildConfig` is as reliable as is `R`, as they are created using the same mechanism. I never ran into the problems reported previously with `BuildConfig` and Eclipse/ADT, and so I have no idea if they were ever cleared up.

Comment: We're using Android Studio and Gradle - I'm relieved to hear it's OK to use.

Comment: You won't actually have your test code in production if BuildConfig.DEBUG is used properly. For this code: `if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { foo(); }` if the constant is false, the whole thing is eliminated. If it's true, only `foo()` will appear in the compiled result.

Comment: it doesn't work for me even after Clean Project on AS 2.2.3 r25. Run App or Debug app report `BuildConfig.DEBUG=true`. Maybe build signed APK work, I don't know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems the issue to which you are referring is specific to ADT + Eclipse. So I believe that if you're using Gradle and Android Studio, this should not be an issue.

**Crucially**: this only occurs if you're using the *Build Automatically* option, and you don't clean your project. Because of this, I would hardly consider this a bug. After all, who says what should and shouldn't be rebuilt whenever you make a code change and have Build Automatically enabled?

As a matter of good practice, *you should always clean and rebuild your project* prior to an actual release, in which case this is a non-issue.

So yes, this is still a problem if you're using this setting, and not rebuilding your project prior to release, and you're still using ADT and Eclipse (which seems to be destined for deprecation).

Here's the discussion of the bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27940

Comment: Thanks for this helpful info. FYI, contrary to the first paragraph, the issue *has* been reported to occur in Android Studio (as of 2.1.1) using Gradle, at least sometimes.

Answer (score 11):

I can confirm this bug still exists, tested with Android Studio 1.2 Build AI-140.1782451 and Gradle 1.1 compiling against Android API Level 21.

The issue is visible with a Nexus 10 on Android 5.0.2 or a similar device.

If you open BuildConfig.DEBUG in the source editor it says:

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
```

But if you debug the app under question, DEBUG stays on false.
This hinders my Retrofit-debugging, as I wanted to enable it conditionally depending on the build-type.

Comment: `Boolean.parseBoolean("true")` return `true`, **But** in past with `ADT` Build (i.e: before `Gradle` Build) was 
`public final static boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean(null);`

Comment: Have you reported this issue to Google yet?

Comment: No, because due to several debug-buildtypes, I now use BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE and check for equality with a certain debug- or staging-type.

Comment: Yes problem still exists in AS 2.2.3 r25

Comment: AS 3.0.1 just has built signed apk in DEBUG mode :(

Answer (score 3):

I had always problems with the predefined variable, so I created my own:

```
  buildTypes {
        // If we use the same keystore for debug and release, we don't have to wipe all preferences
        debug {
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            zipAlignEnabled true

            resValue "bool", "DEBUG", "true"
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
            zipAlignEnabled true

            resValue "bool", "DEBUG", "false"
        }
    }
```

I your code you can read this variable:

```
    if (!MyApplication.get().getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.DEBUG)) {
        // Firebase Crash reporting
        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
    }
```